# List all user's folder access and permission

Tags: java, permissions, sh, directory

I wanted to list all folders and permission of specific user that has access to.
With this, I can audit the user's folder access and its permission. Is it possible to list it via java or shell script?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). Java is not the right tool since it is meant to keep away such low level handling from the programmer.  What is your target operating system?

Comment: Yes, I'm working with a linux servers in particular.

Comment: The tools to gather the permissions depend on the filesystem in use. You should look in the file systems man pages for specific information.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the following article to list all users that have access and their effective permissions

[List users with access to specific Folder](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/367228-list-users-with-access-to-specific-folder)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, I am working with Linux servers. I wanted to list all the folders which a specific user can access to.